# How to project a key into an array to produce an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given this source object:

```
const src = { a: [1, 2, 3]} }
```

I want to transform it to an array of objects representing all combinations(3):

```
[{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}]
```

The code I currently have works, but feels inelegant:

```
const arrPairs = [];
Object.keys(src).map((el) => {
    src[el].forEach(element => {
        arrPairs.push({[el]: element});
    });
});
```

I have a feeling that some combination of map/reduce would do this far cleaner I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const src = {
  a: [1, 2, 3],
};
const result = Object.keys(src).reduce(
  (acc, curr) => [...acc, ...src[curr].map((val) => ({ [curr]: val }))],
  []
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Very elegant use of the spread operator!

Comment: I hadn't realized that reduce() could return an array. All the examples typically show a number or string returned.

Comment: `reduce` can return a single value, So it could be an number, string, array, object, and even function.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the entries with `.flatMap` and map each value to its associated object.

```js
const src = { a: [1, 2, 3], 
              b: [4, 5, 6, 7], 
              c: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12] };
const result = Object.entries(src)
  .flatMap(([key, arr]) => arr.map(val => ({[key]: val})));
console.log(result);
```